# Comparing characters in C throws errors

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I'm new to C, and as a practice I'm creating libraries to handle strings.

Right now I'm making a function called 'indexOf' which returns the index in which a character is placed inside a string.

**main.c** (Read code comments for the info about errors)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "jstring.h"

int main()
{
    char name[] = "Juan";
    printf("The char 'a' is in the index %d \n\n", indexOf(name, 'a'));

    return 0;
}
```

**jstring.h**

```
#include <string.h>

int indexOf(char haystack[], char needle)
{
    int index = 0;
    while(haystack[index] != '\0')
    {
        //Prints char by char untill the needle is found (for testing)
        printf("%c\n", haystack[index]);

        if(strcmp(haystack[index], needle) == 0) //Causes error (app strops working)
        {
            printf("Needle found!");
            return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And if I use next code, it doesn't work

```
if(haystack[index] == needle) //Is never true
{
     printf("Needle found!");
     return index;
}
```

The program knowing the name is "Juan" should return 2 as the index of the position of the character 'a'. I don't know what's wrong with this code, I'm getting used to pointers, maybe is something related to that.

I've searched a lot of StackOverflow questions about comparing characters but haven't found one that doesn't use in the end `strcmp()` or that has a similar goal than my function.

Comment: Don't put function definitions in header files, if you want to split the code into multiple files then use two source files that you link together, and put only the function prototype declaration in the header file.

Comment: I might start reading about the best practices too. I'm used to other languages because I'm web developer, but this is my first week with C

Comment: C have the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29). A translation unit is basically a single source file with all its included header files. The compiler takes this translation unit and creates an object file, which is then fed into a linker that links together all object files and external libraries into a single executable program. Most of this is hidden by the compiler frontend program.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you cannot use

```
if(strcmp(haystack[index], needle) == 0)
```

Beacause of `needle` is not a `null` terminated string. Neither `haystack[index]` it is. To use `haystack[index]` in a `strcmp` you must use `&haystack[index]`.

Second, your code with the simple `==` works well

```
int indexOf(char haystack[], char needle)
{
    int index = 0;
    while(haystack[index] != '\0')
    {
        //Prints char by char untill the needle is found (for testing)
        printf("%c\n", haystack[index]);

        if(haystack[index] == needle ) 
        {
            printf("Needle found!\n");
            return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    char name[] = "Juan";
    printf("The char 'a' is in the index %d \n\n", indexOf(name, 'a'));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happened, I re-tested again after changing some stuff and now, as you say, it works well. Can't know if it was a typo or something. I actually feel very very ashamed now.

Comment: "Beacause of needle is not a null terminated string." -- Neither is haystack[index]. IMHO, both these mistakes should be pointed out, otherwise a novice reader might think the first parameter is ok.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze In the posted code `haystack` is `null` terminated. What are you seeing?

Comment: Yes haystack is a '\0' terminated string, but haystack[index] is not, it's a char. (haystack + index) would be '\0' terminated string again, but this does not help here.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze Ok, I understand what you mean. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

strcmp requires two pointers to char, but you give it two chars. Instead, compare with equality == operator.

Tried your version with == and it works for me. Cannot reproduce that this does not find your index.

Comment: Like if(haystack[index] == needle) ?

Comment: yes. Cannot reproduce that it does not find your index. For me, it prints Needle found!The char 'a' is in the index 2

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what happened, I re-tested again after changing some stuff and now, as you say, it works well. Can't know if it was a typo or something. I actually feel very very ashamed now.